# System of first order ODEs with coherent sinusoidal time varying coefficient

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, dynamical-systems

I have encountered equations of the form $$\frac{{d{\bf{y}}(t)}}{{dt}} = \left( {{A_0} + {A_1}\cos (\omega t)} \right){\bf{y}}(t)$$where ${\bf{y}}$ is a vector and ${{A_0}}$ and ${{A_1}}$ are square matrices with constant (and real) elements. I am interested in the general properties of the unknowns at large times (after transients die away). I have already observed that while stability of the solutions is trivially simple for one degree of freedom systems (requiring ${A_0} < 0$), this criteria has no obvious extension to higher degree systems (to me at least). I would be grateful if someone could points out some references or helpful hints in studying these type of ODEs.

Comment: This is covered under Floquet theory. $B(t)=A_0+A_1cos(\omega t)$ is a periodic matrix with period $2\pi/\omega$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory

Comment: @nonlinearism True, but since this is much more specific than a general periodic function (namely one that has only three frequencies -$\omega$, $0$ and +$\omega$ and then all of these being coherent), I was wondering if there are more powerful methods applicable to this equation.

Comment: Floquet theory gives you everything you need here. Using that, you can convert the system into a autonomous system, and then, just look at eigenvalues to determine stability. I don't know what else you want from a more 'powerful theory' ?

Comment: @nonlinearism Your statements are wrong, since to make the change of the variables, you will need the monodromy matrix, which is surely exists, but there are no regular methods to find it.

Comment: @Artem: In practise, the monodromy matrix is found numerically. I don't see what is wrong in what I said. That is the best you can do in general case.

Comment: @nonlinearism The question deals not with *a general case*, but with a very specific situation, in which it is reasonable to expect to see *more* than the general case provides. Your two comments above dismiss the specific form of the problem, referencing very general, but not helpful here, fact.

Comment: If the matrices $A_0$ and $A_1$ commute, then the problem is completely analogous to the one degree-of-freedom case, just with matrix exponentials replacing the "scalar" one. Then $\mathbf{y}(t) = e^{A_0t+A_1\sin(\omega t)} \mathbf{y_0}$, and as long as the eigenvalues of $A_0$ are negative, then $\mathbf{y}(t)\rightarrow \mathbf{0}$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Of course the more general case where the matrices don't commute is more interesting. I think the Magnus expansion applied to this problem may help in that case.

Comment: @rajb245 Could you elaborate more on the expansion you noted?

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia article has lots of good information on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion
That is a general expansion, but given the simple form of your matrices, I can imagine that the expansion (or terms in it) simplify